# Union Returned Type in C

Tags: c

In the following code, the string "12345678901234567890" cannot be copied completely to an union-type variable. This makes me really confused?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef union
{
    int i;
    long l;
    float f;
    double d;
    void *v;
    char *s;
    char c;
 } UType;

UType NewUType_s(char *s)
{
     UType temp;
     strcpy(temp.s, s);      // If we print temp.s and s here, both of them are "12345678901234567890
     return temp;
}

int main()
{
    UType m;
    m = NewUType_s("12345678901234567890");
    printf("%s\n", m.s);

    return 0;
 }
```

The result is: 1234567890123456 and some special characters?

The solution to this problem may be:

- Solution 1: use `malloc()` for m;
- Solution 2: Change `NewUType_s` style to a pointer function `UType *NewUType_s(char *s);` and everything will work properly,

However, does someone know the reason why the aforementioned program does not have correct result?

Comment: Where does `temp.s` point to? `temp.s` is not initialized.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the use of a union. This: `char *s; strcpy(s, "12345678901234567890");` has exactly the same problem.

Comment: @ouah yes, it is not initialized yet. I forget this little thing :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with this code is that it's undefined behavior to write to a pointer that has not been initialized: `temp.s` has not been assigned a memory block into which you could copy the string, so `strcpy` writes to memory that your program does not own.

Fixing this code is straightforward: allocate memory before copying, like this:

```
UType NewUType_s(char *s)
{
     UType temp;
     temp.s = malloc(strlen(s)+1);
     strcpy(temp.s, s);
     return temp;
}
```

Of course you need to `free` the memory to avoid the memory leak.

Comment: Why not use `strdup`?

Comment: @hyde: `strdup` is non-standard (it's defined by POSIX, but not by ISO C).

Comment: OK! I got the idea :-)

Comment: @KeithThompson Ah, right. Though, if doing application programming for an environment which has it, not using `strdup` isn't a good thing, because code will depend on libraries other than pure standard C library anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling [strcpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) which needs a destination array.  The value of `UType` only contains a `char*`, though, which (when uninitialized) will point to some random place in memory.  You may want [strdup](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup), which will allocate a new string and return a pointer to it:

```
UType NewUType_s(const char *s)
{
     UType temp;
     temp.s = strdup(s);
     return temp;
}
```